# The pst-plot package cannot be found

Tags: errors, texlive, pst-plot

Consider the following (or any other compilable document):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

If I compile using `latex`, I get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `pst-plot.sty' not found.
```

I have an up-to-date TeX Live 2013 distribution.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this (whitout putting [`pst-plot.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-plot/tex/pst-plot.tex) and [`pst-plot.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-plot/latex/pst-plot.sty) in the same directory as the document)?

P.S. The problem hasn't occured before today.

**Update**

Herbert has now fixed it and put the new version on CTAN; thank you for that.

Comment: Have you tried running `kpsewhich pst-plot.sty` in a terminal to see if the file exists in your system?

Comment: Now I have `:)` and it gives me no output at all. (Could it be time to upgrade from Fedora 18 to 19 and see if it helps?)

Comment: So, perhaps accidentally it was removed. Try `tlmgr install pst-plot`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina All I get is `[root@localhost <username>]# tlmgr install pst-plot
tlmgr: package repository http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet` but the problem persists.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Restart your system, and retry.

Comment: @Werner As expected, the Windows trick didn't help.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: `pst-plot` is one of the recently-updated packages. Try `tlmgr update --self --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed`.

Comment: @Werner That was no good either. `:(`

Comment: Something has gone wrong during a recent update of `pst-plot` even I see the same error like you

Comment: after looking into `tlmgr.log` on TL2013/Linux `update: pst-plot (31173 -> 31420)` must have created something strange. Even a restore to `ver:31173` was not working as @Werner suggested

Comment: @texenthusiast Okay. Then at least it isn't something to do with my system; thank you for the clearification.

Comment: @texenthusiast: That's bizarre (and true) that [`pst-plot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-plot) would be removed from the TDS, even though `pst-all` still "requires" it... The problem seems to be that `pst-plot` is now placed in the documentation part of the TDS (`/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pst-plot`)... Hmmmmm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last update of `pst-plot` in TeXLive is wrong. The LaTeX and TeX files
are all in `/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pst-plot` and not in the correct directories:

```
/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-plot/
/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-plot/
```

Wait for the next update or move the files from the doc directory to the right one by yourself and then run `texhash`.